# Is this conjecture equivalent to Polignac's conjecture?

Tags: nt.number-theory, prime-numbers, goldbach-type-problems, prime-constellations

Under Goldbach's conjecture denote by $r_{0}(n)$ for $n$ a large enough composite integer the quantity $\inf\{r\geq 0,(n-r,n+r)\in\mathbb{P}^{2}\}$, by $k_{0}(n)$ the quantity $\pi(n+r_{0}(n))-\pi(n-r_{0}(n))$ and by $d_{k}$ the diameter of an admissible $k$-tuple that is a prime constellation.

Define the compacity of $n$, denoted by $\kappa(n)$, as the quantity $\frac{d_{1+k_{0}(n)}}{2r_{0}(n)}$.

Is the following conjecture equivalent to Polignac's conjecture (which says that for any positive integer $u$ there are infinitely many positive integers $m$ such that $p_{m+1}-p_{m}=2u$) or is it stronger?

Moreover, is the set of values of $\kappa(n)$ dense in $(0,1]$?

Compacity conjecture: any value of $\kappa(n)$ that is attained at least once is attained infinitely many times as $n$ runs among the composite integers beyond some absolute threshold $C$.